# Auto mount usb drive to raspberry pi without boot

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, usb, mount

I have raspberry pi 3B. It's running on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch). I saw some tutorials about mounting usb drive to it but mostly there are 2 ways:

-mount that drive manually,
-mount that drive automatically at boot

and I'm looking for mounting that usb drive automatically at lifetime (without boot) on specific path. I assume that there is no option to do that on linux configuration but maybe there is an option to do that by python script?

My drive has exfat file system (there is no other drive with that file system), so it should be east to manage uuid and mounting that. I think that it should looks like:

1. Background process that looks once for a while that 'exfat' drive is connected
2. If yes get his UUID
3. Mount that drive with that UUID on specific path*

*that path should also exist when that usb drive isn't connected

Can I do that like that? Or maybe there is already a solution for this?

Comment: Yeah, thats precisely what `/etc/fstab` is for. I don't understand what you mean by "without boot" though, if you meant without a boot device linux wont even work..?

Comment: @CryptoAlgorithm that usb drive isn't drive with software on which that rpi is running. There is just some data that I need to use. And I just want to see that files without making rpi boots again.

Comment: Oh I misread your question, you'd like the drive to be auto mounted when it's plugged in? Raspbian already has this feature, unless youre using some other OS?

Comment: @CryptoAlgorithm exactly auto-mount when it's plugged in.

Comment: Are you using Raspbian desktop? It includes auto mounting support by default.

Comment: @CryptoAlgorithm just console. I want something to do once and didn't think about it again. I mean config that will works for different usb drives or script that will monitor pluged devices and will give ma access to data

Comment: Please take a look at and accept my answer if it has helped you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`usbmount` is a nifty package that adds `udev` hooks for auto mounting/unmounting.

Simply install it with:

```bash
sudo apt install usbmount
```

There appears to be an [issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100312/raspberry-4-usbmount-not-working) that stops it working properly, and in a nutshell the solution is as follows:

1. Edit the following file in an editor:

   ```bash
   sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service
   ```
2. Look for the line with the contents: `PrivateMounts=yes`
3. Change the `yes` in the line to `no`, like so: `PrivateMounts=no`
4. Save the file and reload the `udev` daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl restart systemd-udevd
   ```

   (or just reboot)

Your USB devices should now auto mount at `/media/usb0`, `/media/usb1` and so on.

Comment: I don't have param "PrivateMounts". My whole file looks like:
https://imgur.com/a/nbwbZqD

Comment: If thats the case, try ignoring those instructions and seeing if it works that way.

Comment: It doesn't work. Folders usb0 are empty like drive isn't connected